# Topmost window focus

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winforms

I have a very strange issue.

I have two application. 
For example:
Process1.exe launching Process2.exe. (This is done using Process.WaitForExit(), Process1 will wait till Process2 gets closed.)
Sample code for this case.

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = strFilePath;
string strDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(strFilePath);
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = strDirectory;
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

Here assume that Process2.exe launching multile windows. (Assuming 3 windows)

Now from the 3rd window in the Process2.exe, we are launching remote desktop using a pre-configured RDP(Remote Desktop Protocal) file. 
This is done by using the below code.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process remoteWindow = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
remoteWindow.StartInfo.FileName = MSTSC_PROCESS_NAME;
remoteWindow.StartInfo.Arguments = strUrl;
remoteWindow.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
result = remoteWindow.Start();
```

Now the issue is when we close the remote desktop window, focus is moving to Process1.exe. Actually windows should retain focus on Process2.exe

Also, this issue is not occuring in all kind of PC's. This issue is occurring specifically in Panasonic CF-C1 laptop.

OS: Windows 7

Is this a windows related issue?  or Any suggestions will help.

Comment: It depends, Windows normally returns the foreground to whatever window the user interacted with last.  It isn't very clear if "Process2" creates any window at all.  You do open the door to this mishap, you should *never* allow your window to be reactivated when your program goes catatonic on the Process.WaitForExit() call.  At a minimum you should hide your window.  Or just not go catatonic, use the Exited event instead.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for your inputs.  Also process 1 and 2 is a huge process, for simplicity i have mentioned process 1 and 2.  Process 2 creates windows.Also windows are not re-created.